# salt attribute(key/value) replacement based on particular stanza

Tags: salt-stack

Using salt i want to find the attribute(key) and replace it with value based on specific stanza. The attribute(key) is present in multiple times in a file under different stanzas. I want to find my attribute under specific stanza and replace with value.

### Example:

```
output.kafka:
  # Boolean flag to enable or disable the output module.
  enabled:
```

I need to find enabled: under output.kafka: and replace it with value. The enabled: attribute present multiple times in my file.

Thanks
Bala.

Comment: what is the path of kafka config which holds the key and value ? is this config file is a json file ?

Comment: In the given example enabled: is the key. Will read the value (true or false) from the pillar file.

Comment: I mean where will it be modified (on the minion) ?

Comment: yes it will be modified on the minion.

Comment: Could tell me about its path on the minion ?

Comment: i need to update the values in the file /etc/filebeat/filebeat.yml on minion.

Answer (score 1):

Salt has a few commands like `file.line`, `file.replace` and `file.blockreplace` that can modify an existing file, but I highly recommend managing the whole file using `file.managed`. It makes for a less brittle experience.

Here's an example based off your question:

Pillar top file:

```
cat /srv/pillar/top.sls

base:
  '*':
    - common
  'minion01':
    - minion01kafkasettings
```

Set our pillar data:

```
cat /srv/pillar/minion01kafkasettings.sls

kafka_output: True
```

Here's our filebeat template:

```
cat /srv/salt/filebeat.tmpl

output.kafka:
  # Boolean flag to enable or disable the output module.
  enabled: {{ pillar.get('kafka_output', True) }}
```

Here's the filebeat Salt sls file:

```
cat /srv/salt/filebeat.sls

the_filebeat_file:
  file.managed:
    - name: /etc/filebeat/filebeat.yml
    - template: jinja
    - user: root
    - group: root
```

Then we can run the following:

Refresh our pillar data

```
salt 'minion01' saltutil.refresh_pillar
```

Then apply the sls file:

```
salt 'minion01' state.sls filebeat
```

Comment: Could you check my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/44008761/2336650) ?

Answer (score 0):

I have another theory using `file.seralize` that might work but not in its current state, Maybe [Dave](https://stackoverflow.com/users/114866/utah-dave) could help.

```
{% set json_data = salt.cp.get_file_str('/etc/filebeat/filebeat.yml') | load_yaml  %}


{% do json_data.update({'enabled': pillar.get('kafka_output', True) }) %}

update_config:
  file.serialize:
    - name: /etc/filebeat/filebeat.yml
    - user: root
    - group: root
    - mode: 644
    - formatter: yaml
    - dataset: |
        {{ json_data | yaml(False)| indent(8) }}
```

This state should load the whole configuration file then you can modify any of its values based on your pillar setting using the `do` statement in your case it could be

```
{% do json_data.update({'enabled': pillar.get('kafka_output', True) }) %}
```

The config file is populated but not as exepcted as the result will be as following:

```
'enabled: true

  status: active

'
```

Note there are quotes and the yaml is not intended correctly, is there another way to make it work ? I will update this answer if I found any new results

Comment: That's an interesting approach. I think it still has the problem of being brittle if the config file changes.